# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier index out of bound

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

[**=> Demo Project @ GitHub <=**](https://github.com/stuffmc/InternalTableView/tree/master)

I'm having a `UITableViewController` which has a `TableView` in which I have a Cell which has another `TableView` in it.

When that internal `TableView` tries `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` for indexPath `(1,0)` the app crashes with

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', 
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Although that internal `TableView` clearly has 3 sections. The stack trace being:

```
-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 190
-[UITableViewDataSource tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:] + 61
-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 1711
+[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 65
-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 312
-[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 271
```

Because of the trace, I tried implementing

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
              indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Int {
  return 0
}
```

but then the app crashes at

```
-[UITableViewDataSource tableView:viewForFooterInSection:]
```

with the same `index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]`...

The implementation is relatively irrelevant IMHO, but there it is

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
              cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  if tableView.tag == 0 {
    return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
  }
  if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? UITableViewCell {
    return cell
  }
  return UITableViewCell() // Shouldn't happen.
}
```

I'm not super proud of that last line :) but what else would you do to please the compiler? I never reach that line. The crash clearly happens in the internal `TableView` which has a `tag` of 1.

Comment: Can you post full method?

Comment: What is the implementation of your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: @Amit89 @madboy I added my implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, although it's fairly irrelevant I think in that case. It crashes on `dequeue` like I said.

Comment: Regarding the last line, if you know that `dequeueReusableCellWithidentifier` will never return `nil`, then rather than using optional binding (`if let` with `as?`), could simply force unwrap it (`let` with `as!`), and then that `if` statement goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the call to

```
super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

But `MasterViewController` is a subclass of `UITableViewController`, so you're calling the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of the base class `UITableViewController`. I think understand the intent of your code ("hey, I want the child `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to call the parent's if appropriate"), but you are conflating the class hierarchy with the view hierarchy. This is not the way to achieve what you want.

Instead, you could do something like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView.tag == 0 {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ParentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    }

    return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChildCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
}
```

This instantiates one cell type for `tag` of `0` and another for `1`. Note, I've changed the storyboard to make both table views to use dynamic prototypes and I've changed the identifiers for the two table views as indicated above.

Frankly, I think it's a mistake to have a single object try to serve as the delegate for two different types of table views. If you really had one view controller and two table views, I think it's much cleaner to implement a custom delegate object for each table view, instantiate them as needed, set the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the appropriate table views. That way, you avoid having to litter all of the delegate methods with "if table 0 do *x* otherwise do *y*" logic.

But, more broadly, I would advise against a table view within a tableview.

Comment: You are totally right that it was a mistake. Thanks for your awesome answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the answer. Basically, I knew it wasn't a super smart idea to have a TableView inside another one, the first one being Static the other one Dynamic (which I should have stated).

Then I remembered as soon as you implement any of the delegates (e.g. `cellForRow`) you'll need to implement them all...

To sumarize, what I wanted to do can be done with only 1 TableView and using the `TableViewHeader`, which is what I'll do and what people should do, if they start seeing those weird messages coming.

Comment: "as soon as you implement any of the delegates ... you'll need to implement them all". No, that's not true. If you specify a `dataSource`, you must implement the required methods, which are solely `numberOfRowsForSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. If you have static table view, you shouldn't specify data source at all.

Answer (score -1):

Your second if statement should be wrapped in the first (if tableView.tag == 0). Right now, it is called for both tableViews, thus the error.

Comment: No, if `tag` was zero, he calls `return`.